# Чем выделить этот обособленный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Куйбышев() для тех молодых телезрителей, которые не знают() – это Самара.*

Что это за обособленный оборот и чем его выделить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вставная конструкция.

> 1. Вставные конструкции (слова, сочетания слов, предложения) содержат дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки к
>      основному высказыванию. Вставные конструкции менее тесно связаны с
>      предложением, чем вводные, и потому резко выпадают из его структуры.
>      Выражая дополнительные сообщения, они требуют более значительного
>      выделения в составе предложения, нежели вводные конструкции, как
>      правило, заключающие в себе отношение к высказанному, его оценку.
>      Именно эта смысловая самостоятельность вставных конструкций объясняет
>      необходимость использования для их выделения скобок и тире.
>
> Например: *С 1851 года деятельно работал Сибирский (затем
>   Восточно-Сибирский) отдел Географического общества (Расп.); Нас хорошо
>   кормили, но воды – не питьевой, а для умывания – было мало (Кав.);
>   Иногда дни сверкали лучше летних – белизна замороженного снега в упор
>   сопротивлялась солнечному огню – и чистый воздух остро мерцал от
>   колкого холода и тягучего тепла (Плат.); Валерия – так звали девушку,
>   от тоски по которой я сбежал из деревни в Москву, – слушала меня,
>   мечтательно глядя перед собой (Сол.).*
>
> 2. Знаки препинания при вставных конструкциях Скобками выделяются:
>
> 1) вставные конструкции, дополняющие или поясняющие содержание
>   основного предложения. Например:  *Я не успел хорошенько заметить его
>   лица (коляска слишком быстро промчалась мимо); но мне показалось, что
>   он был глубоко тронут (Т.); Возвратясь в свою комнату (она находилась
>   во флигеле и была почти вся загромождена коваными сундуками), Гаврила
>   сперва выслал вон свою жену… (Т.); Пети не было дома (он пошёл к
>   товарищу, с которым намеревался из ополчения перейти в действующую
>   армию) (Л.Т.); Проехав какие-то австрийские войска, Ростов заметил,
>   что следующая за тем часть линии (это была гвардия) уже вступила в
>   дело (Л.Т.); Дисканты и альты (иногда басы и тенора) в эти хоры
>   набирались из учеников (Пом.).*
>
> 2) Вставные конструкции, представляющие собой попутные авторские
>   замечания. Например: *Поверьте (совесть в том порукой), супружество
>   нам будет мукой (П.); Не отвечай те, я знаю, что вы в этом не
>   признаетесь, потому что Грушницкий убит (она перекрестилась) (Л.);
>   «Господа, — сказал он (голос его был спокоен, хотя тоном ниже
>   обыкновенного). — Господа, к чему пустые споры?» (Л.); Быстро, но
>   горячо прошла в душе моей страсть (иначе я не могу назвать ее)  ловить
>   и собирать бабочек (Акс.); Но Господь Бог ведает (тут он поднял руку
>   над головою), что скорее шар земной в раздробление придёт, чем мне от
>   своего слова отступиться или… (тут он даже фыркнул)или струсить… (Т.);
>   Я не понимал (теперь я понял), что я делал с близкими мне существами
>   (Гарш.); Теперь, когда с посещения Даши прошло больше недели, ему
>   стало казаться удивительным, как могла незаметно (он с ней не сразу
>   даже и поздоровался) и просто (вошла, села, положила муфту на колени)
>   появиться в их оголтелой квартире эта девушка (А.Т.).*
>
> 3) Вставные конструкции, поясняющие отдельные слова в основном
>   предложении. Например: *Нет, вы (или ты) этого не должны знать! (Л.);
>   А где стара? (Так он обыкновенно называл жену свою.) (Г.); Командиры
>   бросили книги, карты (географические, других на корабле не было),
>   разговоры и стремительно побежали на палубу (Гонч.)*
>
> 4) Вставные конструкции, синтаксически связанные с основным
>   предложением, но выключенные из него и носящие присоединительный
>   характер. Например:  *Увидя, что мужик, трудясь над дугами, их
>   прибыльно сбывает с рук (а дуги гнут с терпеньем и не вдруг), Медведь
>   задумал жить такими же трудами (Кр.); Враги его, друзья его (что,
>   может быть, одно и то же) его честили так и сяк (П.); Издеваться над
>   ним (и ещё в официальной газете) нехорошо (П.); Отец лишился
>   обыкновенной своей твёрдости, и горесть его (обыкновенно немая)
>   изливалась в горьких жалобах (П.)*
>
> 5) Вставные вопросительные и восклицательные конструкции и отдельные
>   слова, выражающие эмоции автора или его отношение к высказанным
>   словам, к цитатам. Например: *…Быть может (лестная надежда!), укажет
>   будущий невежда на мой прославленный портрет… (П.); Мы узнали от него
>   самого, что он, г. Савельев, решился посвятить все способности (чьи?)
>   разработанию (разрабатыванию?) отечественной истории (Бел.).*

https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/256-vstavnyekonstrukcii.html

У нас попутное замечание. Я бы взяла в скобки, но можно и тире:

Куйбышев (для тех молодых телезрителей, которые не знают) – это Самара.

Куйбышев - для тех молодых телезрителей, которые не знают, – это Самара.

Comment: Да, а вот насчёт тире, разве можно их так ставить, если в предложении оно будет контактировать с тире, которое уже идет само по себе? Разве здесь не один верный вариант – поставить скобки?

Comment: Ничего страшного, всё контактирует нормально: тире стоит, а по какой причине поставлено - другой вопрос. Бывает же так, что запятая закрывает оборот и одновременно разделяет простые предложения в сложном, мы же не ставим две запятые.